# Discriminant property for enum in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

What would be the easiest way to have a switch working for a discriminant union of enums?
Basically I'm trying to emulate some kind of pattern matching.

```
enum Fruit {
  Apple,
  Banana,
  Orange
}

enum Vegetable {
  Tomato,
  Carrot,
  Potato
}

type Grocery = Fruit | Vegetable;

function checkStuff(grocery: Grocery) {
  switch (grocery.kind) {
    case "Fruit":
      doStuff(grocery);
      break;
    case "Vegetable":
      doOtherStuff(grocery);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fist, in your case enums are numeric based in Typescript. That means in your example `Fruit.Apple as Grocery === Vegetable.Tomato as Grocery;`
 can be true :)

I suggest to go with string based enums and check the following example (however in more complex situations where the enum value doesn't matter you'd better create an interface with a "Kind" and enum value field):

```
function doFruitStuff(a: Fruit){
     //  do something with the fruit
}

function doVegetableStuff(v: Vegetable){
     // do something with the vegetable
}

enum Fruit {
Apple = 'Apple',
Banana = 'Banana',
Orange = 'Orange'
}

enum Vegetable {
Tomato = 'Tomato',
Carrot = 'Carrot',
Potato = 'Potato'
}

type Grocery = Fruit | Vegetable;

function checkStuff(grocery: Grocery) {
    switch (grocery) {
        case Fruit.Apple:
        case Fruit.Banana:
        case Fruit.Orange:
            doFruitStuff(grocery);
            break;
        case Vegetable.Tomato:
        case Vegetable.Carrot:
        case Vegetable.Potato:
            doVegetableStuff(grocery);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }  
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about this solution. But yes, you're right on more complex examples with more values in the enum and where I don't care about 
the values it could get too verbose.  

I was thinking about the interface solution with the "kind" and "value" fields but I'm not sure how it with look like when using those types. For eg. let's say we have  
interface FruitInterface { kind: "Fruit"; value: Fruit } when I'll have to use this i'll have to do something like var myFruit = {value: Fruit.Apple} instead of just var myFruit = Fruit.Apple ... right? It doesn't make me too happy. :)