# FP-TS Equivalent of Lodash or Ramda `cond`?

Tags: fp-ts

Trying to figure out how to model multiple cases with fp-ts.  Unsure whether my mental model of this operation should be different in fp-ts, whether I can't find the right function to use, or such a function doesn't exist.

For reference, https://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond (same signature+behavior in Lodash)

Example cases would be loading/loaded states, or splitting cases on an enum.  E.g.,

```js
enum abcd {a,b,c,d}

const getCaseResult = cond([
  [is(a), getResultA],
  [is(b), getResultB],
  [is(c), getResultC],
  [is(d), getResultD],
])

getCaseResult('a') // returns result of getResultA('a')
```

Comment: I'm not aware of anything fp-ts specific here, I'd probably go with something like a discriminated switch block here, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434762/discriminant-property-for-enum-in-typescript

Comment: Did you take a look at https://github.com/gvergnaud/ts-pattern? Maybe it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @bugs , for enums, that makes sense, and does improve performance over cond.  Tradeoff with swtich is lower reusability, deeper nesting, and mixed responsibilities of choosing+executing the action.

Comment: @DenisFrezzato , thanks for sharing that.  Interesting approach.  Wildcards are intriguing.  It also seems more verbose, and the syntax less flexible than cond's predicates+actions.  It's also lower flexibility since it's chained instead of piped.  Regardless, good food for thought on functions to use with cond. 

Comment: @Adam Little late to the party but this may be what you're looking for: https://samhh.github.io/fp-ts-std/modules/Function.ts.html#guard

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of digging into the type definitions for Ramda because I was curious how they were handling the types if in fact the predicate functions were type guards. It turns out they don't use type guards to narrow the types.
[See DefinitelyTyped Code](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/ramda/index.d.ts#L411-L417).

Incidentally the comment there actually invalidates the type definitions they're giving:

> If none of the predicates matches, fn returns undefined.

But the types state it returns an `R` not `R | undefined`. I took a crack at implementing `cond` with equivalent types using `fp-ts` utilities, because as some commenters pointed out, it doesn't look like `fp-ts` has a built in equivalent to cond.

Would something like this work for you?

```js
import { reduce } from "fp-ts/lib/Array";
import { alt, some, none, fold, Option } from "fp-ts/Option";
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

type CondPair<T extends any[], R> = [
  (...args: T) => boolean,
  (...args: T) => R
];
const cond = <T extends any[], R>(pairs: Array<CondPair<T, R>>) => (
  ...args: T
): R | undefined =>
  pipe(
    pairs,
    reduce(
      none,
      (prev: Option<R>, [pred, res]: CondPair<T, R>): Option<R> =>
        pipe(
          prev,
          alt(() => (pred(...args) ? some(res(...args)) : none))
        )
    ),
    fold(
      () => undefined,
      (r) => r
    )
  );

enum abcd {
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d
}

const is = <T>(t: T) => (x: unknown) => t === x;

function isResultA(a: abcd) {
  return 1;
}
function isResultB(b: abcd) {
  return 2;
}
function isResultC(c: abcd) {
  return 3;
}
function isResultD(d: abcd) {
  return 4;
}

const getCaseResult = cond([
  [is(abcd.a), isResultA],
  [is(abcd.b), isResultB],
  [is(abcd.c), isResultC],
  [is(abcd.d), isResultD]
]);

for (let x of [abcd.a, abcd.b, abcd.c, abcd.d]) {
  console.log(getCaseResult(x));
} // Logs 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively
```